# Multiple labels for one layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

Is it possible to show two or more labels for one layer?

For example - one label will show the name of a school and the 2nd label will show the number of students? They should be completely different labels. Editing one label (its buffer, font, background etc.) will not affect the other labels

Comment: I don't really agree with you @underdark as the question is: *...1 label will show the name of a school and the 2nd label with show the number of students...* I asked myself the same question wich is not: how to get a multiple-lines label (by means of concatenation)? So here is my question: is it possible to display 2 separated labels for one point from one sible layer? Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to open a new thread which explains exactly how your use case differs from what is described in the linked question. It shows how to create a label from multiple fields which can be adapted to show name and number of students.

Comment: The only way I can think to do this would be to make a dummy layer, format it so you can't see the dummy layer, then label the first layer with 'school', the second (invisible layer) with '# students'. You can then choose a different style of font etc for each layer's label. Might need to offset them specifically though, and that will take some fiddling around.

Answer (score 32):

[here](http://anitagraser.com/2011/06/15/multi-line-labels-in-qgis/) is a link for multi line labels. The syntax is like:

```
Field1 || '\n' || Field2
```

with \n for new line

Make sure you use a backslash '\' instead of a forward slash '/'.

Comment: this answer is neater, as it manages longer labels better by splitting each label onto a new line. Also, you can use `+` instead of `||`, at least in QGIS 3.x

Answer (score 20):

In the menu layer labelling you can press on the "E"-symbol and then create a combination of different labels.

Showing school and number of student should look something like this:

```
    "Name of School" || ', ' || "Number of students"
```