# Label containing multiple fields

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, fields-attributes, expression

I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83686/multiple-labels-for-one-layer-in-qgis#) question and the anwser did help me somewhat. But my ''code'' for the label seems to have some sort of error. It won't show any label when I apply it. I've tried the following examples to try and get it to work:

[image: Try 1]
[image: Try 2]
[image: Try 3]

Does anyone have advice for me to try and make a working label? I'm not very wellversed in making codes/rules like this.

Edit:
[image]

Comment: So I have to replace all '||' with '()'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat()`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#concat) function. It ignores `NULL` values and returns an empty string `''` instead of `NULL` and therefore gives you a result if one or more fields are `NULL`. This is not the case for `||` concatenator. `||` returns `NULL` as result if at least one field/value is `NULL`.

Use concat the following:

```
concat("myfield_a",'my string a',"myfield_b",' --> ',NULL,"myfield_c",'blablabla')
```

To skip concatenations of empty fields, e.g. `concat("field_a",' is empty')` you can use a simple `if()` statement: `concat("field_a", if("field_a" is null,'',' is empty'))` or `coalesce()` together with `||`: `concat(coalesce("field_a"||' is empty'),'',"field_b", ' is never empty')`

Comment: Yes this worked, thank you! Do you know if its possible to add enters so I can order the fields vertically? And is there maybe a way for the fieldname to not show is the fieldvalue is null?

Comment: Ah I already managed to do so x) I did mean linebreak. I'll add a picture of what I have now. Maybe adding coalesce() will be what I need. In the picture I showed I want to hide the lines ''Glas'', ''Lamp'' and ''Benen naald'', because there is no values in those fields for certain points

Comment: I can't make this one work. But thank you for your help!