# QGIS multitude rule-based labelling returns wrong label order

Tags: qgis, style

I have applied a multitude of rule-based labeling to my project. Some things, unfortunately, go wrong, as I don't know how to make the correct order of the appearing labels.
I would like to have the length value as the first and the size as the second. In nearly half of the cases, the order is wrong.

[image]

Is there any way to fix it within the rule-based labeling?
I tried to change the placement from Horizontal to Parallel and Curved, the same as setting priority as high, but unfortunately it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

By using this thread:

[Multiple labels for one layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83686/multiple-labels-for-one-layer-in-qgis)

We can simply attach another value to our current formula and build the label from two values

```
     "Length (m)" || 'm ' || "Cable Size"
```

This is the simplest approach to this problem

[image]